# Creating paypal invoice with agelleye: error 520002

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

i get an error, 520002  - Internal Error from PayPal, when I try to create and send an invoice. 
I can do it with ci-merchant but no with angelleye (for codeigniter). When I try to create it I get this errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
    <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
        <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
        <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
    </requestEnvelope>
    <invoice xmlns="">
        <merchantEmail xmlns="">lalanzaos@gmail.com</merchantEmail>
        <payerEmail xmlns="">oscar73@gmail.com</payerEmail>
        <itemList xmlns="">
            <item xmlns="">
                <name xmlns="">Clases de idiomas (EspaÃ±ol)</name>
                <description xmlns="">Dia/s: 2014-08-08</description>
                <date xmlns="">2014-08-22</date>
                <quantity xmlns="">1</quantity><unitPrice xmlns="">11.00</unitPrice>
            </item>
        </itemList>
        <currencyCode xmlns="">USD</currencyCode>
        <invoiceDate xmlns="">2014-08-22</invoiceDate>
        <dueDate xmlns="">2014-08-22</dueDate>
        <referrerCode xmlns="">AngellEYE_PHPClass</referrerCode>
    </invoice>
</CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest>




<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/pt">
    <responseEnvelope>
        <timestamp>2014-08-22T04:12:25.170-07:00</timestamp>
        <ack>Failure</ack>
        <correlationId>87f10d36a1e29</correlationId>
        <build>11737381</build>
    </responseEnvelope>
    <error>
        <errorId>520002</errorId>
        <domain>PLATFORM</domain>
        <subdomain>Application</subdomain>
        <severity>Error</severity>
        <category>Application</category>
        <message>Internal Error</message>
    </error>
</ns3:FaultMessage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the date format is not being correctly passed . It should be like below :

```
<invoiceDate xmlns="">2014-08-23T22:33:35</invoiceDate>

<dueDate xmlns="">2014-08-24T22:33:35</dueDate>
```

It should be working fine with this formatting .